# Oracle AQ delete and re-create Agent when dequeue hangs

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g

I have this weird problem in Oracle 11g.

I have an advanced queue, XALOTUPUT_Q, and an subscriber agent 'lasernet'. When I have been debugging from my .net code the agent seems to stop working and i then have to delete and create the angent and then i can dequeue again.
Has anybody had the same problem and how did you fix it?

Agent pl/sql code

```
DECLARE
   /* Add subscribers lasernet to the suscriber list: */
   subscriber          sys.aq$_agent; 
BEGIN 
   subscriber := sys.aq$_agent ('lasernet', 'XALOUTPUT_Q', 0); 
   DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER(
   queue_name => 'XAL_SUPERVISOR.XALOUTPUT_Q', 
   subscriber => subscriber, 
   RULE => 'tab.user_data.beskedtype = ''lasernet''' , 
   TRANSFORMATION => null, 
   QUEUE_TO_QUEUE => false, 
   DELIVERY_MODE => 3);-- persistens or buffered   
END; 

DECLARE
   /* Remove subscribers from the subscriber list: */
   subscriber          sys.aq$_agent; 
BEGIN 
    subscriber := sys.aq$_agent ('lasernet', null, null);     
   DBMS_AQADM.remove_SUBSCRIBER(
   queue_name => 'XAL_SUPERVISOR.XALOUTPUT_Q', 
   subscriber => subscriber);   
END;
```

my .net code  it is placed in a thread task and are running as a win service

```
 public bool Listen()
        {
            var conListen = new OracleConnection(_constr);
            conListen.Open();       
            XALOUTPUT_T queueItem = null;
            var threadNumber = CountThread(SUBSCRIBER_1);
            Console.WriteLine("TestListen()");           
            OracleAQQueue queueListen = new OracleAQQueue("XALOUTPUT_Q", conListen);           
            string subscriber = "lasernet";
            var listenConsumers = new string[2] { subscriber, "vau_mail" };

            try
            {            
                queueListen.MessageType = OracleAQMessageType.Udt;
                queueListen.UdtTypeName = "XALOUTPUT_T";
                queueListen.DequeueOptions.ConsumerName = subscriber.ToUpper();
                queueListen.DequeueOptions.DeliveryMode = OracleAQMessageDeliveryMode.PersistentOrBuffered;
                queueListen.DequeueOptions.Visibility = OracleAQVisibilityMode.Immediate;
                queueListen.DequeueOptions.Wait = 5;

                var consumer = queueListen.Listen(listenConsumers, 5); 

                if (consumer.ToUpper() == "LASERNET")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[Listen Thread] Listen returned... Dequeuing...");
                    OracleAQMessage deqMsg = queueListen.Dequeue(queueListen.DequeueOptions);
                    XALOUTPUT_T result = (XALOUTPUT_T)deqMsg.Payload;
                    try
                    {
                        if (deqMsg != null && deqMsg.Payload is XALOUTPUT_T queuePayload)
                            queueItem = queuePayload;
                        var operation = SendDataToLasernet(queueItem, threadNumber).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        queueListen.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                else                
                    Console.WriteLine("Consumer not found..."); 
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" .net - Error: {0}", e.Message);
                queueListen.Dispose();
                conListen.Close();
                Listen();
            }
            finally
            {
                queueListen.Dispose();
                conListen.Close();
                Listen();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Did you check the oracle log files? https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2295022/location-of-alert-log-in-11g

Comment: no - ill try that

Comment: cant find any logs - so if anyone else has a good idea, please give a hint

Comment: Did you see following in the link : "If environment variable ORACLE_BASE is not set, DIAGNOSTIC_DEST is set to ORACLE_HOME/log." You can change you environmental variable using following : https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/121664-set-new-user-system-environment-variables-windows.html